# how to specify validator order with respect to cross field validation

Tags: spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am trying to validate a bean with two composite fields. These two fields are interdependent on each other in 4 different ways. Hence I created 4 different validators(to reuse) and applied them as a class level constraint on the bean. It is working, but the validators are not getting called in specific order. I need to enforce this order, as validators itself depend on each other. Please let me know if there is any other better way of doing this.

Spring-MVC, Spring 3.2.2, Hibernate validator 4.3.0.Final.

```
@ValidatorClassLevel
public class BeanClass{

@ValidatorProperty1 
   String property1;
   String property2; 
}

@ValidatorProperty2
@ValidatorProp1And2
@ValidatorProp1Or2
@Target( { TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {Property12Validator.class})
@Documented
public @interface ValidatorClassLevel{

    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation [group sequences](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-defining-group-sequences) to enforce a certain order of the constraints.